# Ingress path not working with Azure App Gateway Ingress Controller, even though external IP of service works

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have deployed a service on AKS, with ingress supported by Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller. My issue is that the routing defined in the ingress returns 502 Bad Gateway, even though the service which the route points to works fine.

if I add `type: LoadBalancer` from the service and thereby exposing it with it's own external IP, then I can call that IP with the REST endpoint of the associated app without errors.

Output of `kubectl describe svc organization-service -n default`:

```
Name:              organization-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       Selector:  app=organization-service
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.0.96.206
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        5001/TCP
Endpoints:         15.0.0.6:5001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

AGW Ingress Controller logs:

```
I0917 16:28:24.300899       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:177] BEGIN AppGateway deployment
I0917 16:28:54.715631       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:185] Applied generated Application Gateway configuration
I0917 16:28:54.715668       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:200] cache: Updated with latest applied config.
I0917 16:28:54.716136       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:204] END AppGateway deployment
I0917 16:28:54.716149       1 controller.go:151] Completed last event loop run in: 30.516738446s
I0917 16:28:55.768237       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:164] cache: Config has NOT changed! No need to connect to ARM.
I0917 16:28:55.768260       1 controller.go:151] Completed last event loop run in: 51.85209ms
E0917 16:29:30.646794       1 ingress_rules.go:159] Ingress default/organization-service references non existent Service default/organization-service. Please correct the Service section of your Kubernetes YAML
E0917 16:29:30.647006       1 backendhttpsettings.go:89] Unable to get the service [default/organization-service]
E0917 16:29:30.647113       1 context.go:248] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
E0917 16:29:30.647126       1 backendaddresspools.go:103] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
E0917 16:29:30.647207       1 context.go:248] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
E0917 16:29:30.647215       1 backendaddresspools.go:103] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
E0917 16:29:30.647230       1 context.go:248] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
E0917 16:29:30.647235       1 backendaddresspools.go:103] Code="ErrorFetchingEnpdoints" Message="Endpoint not found for default/organization-service"
```

YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: organization-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: organization-service
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: organization-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: organization-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: organization-service
  labels:
    app: organization-service
spec:
  containers:
  - image: acrprodnortheurope.azurecr.io/organization-service:deploy
    name: organization-service
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5001
      protocol: TCP
    env:
      - name: SQL_SERVER_CONN_STR
        valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: organization-service
              key: conn_str
    resources: {}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If possible check logs of ingress controller

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I updated my OP with the recent logs after having redeployed the YAML.

Comment: Add output of `kubectl describe svc organization-service -n default`

Comment: Updated with output.

Comment: Do you see  the IP `15.0.0.6` in the backend pool of azure application gateway UI?

Comment: Yes. I also tested AGW with the default aspnetapp image, this works fine. The problem occurs when I use my own image. I'm wondering if this may have something to do with the fact that the aspnetapp image serves a web app, and my image serves a REST API, and I therefore may have to do some additional configuration in my YAML setup?

Comment: Does the app listen on port `5001` ? . Are you able to `curl http://15.0.0.6:5001` from another pod? Is there anything extra in the deployment yaml of `aspnetapp` image ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found any solution for this issue?